# Core data relationship delete action - cascade vs. nullify vs. deny vs. no action

Tags: iphone, core-data

Core Data is throwing me for a loop. I have two objects:, Card and CardSet, which are in a many-to-many relationship with each other, i.e. you could have cards 1, 2, and 3 in CardSet A and cards 2, 4, and 5 in CardSet B.

I am trying to set up my delete actions so that:

1. If I delete a Card, it is removed from all CardSets to which it belongs. (i.e., delete Card 2, then CardSet A = {1, 3} and CardSet B = {4, 5})
2. If I delete a CardSet, then all of the cards in the set are deleted EXCEPT those which belong to another set. I.e. delete CardSet A, then CardSet B remains {2, 4, 5}.

My data structure has two relationships which define this many-to-many relationship: CardSet.cards and Card.cardSets. The delete action for CardSet.cards is `cascade` (so if I delete a CardSet, all of its cards are deleted) and my delete action for Card.cardSets is `null` (so if I delete a single card, the cardSets are not nuked as well).

However, with this current setup if I delete CardSet A, then CardSet B remains {2, 4, 5} **BUT** Card 2 has actually been deleted from the data store which leads to a core data error when trying to access the CardSet. What should I be doing here to make sure that cards are not deleted if they are still being held by another CardSet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to set `Card.cardsets` to `deny` instead of `null`.  That way, the card will not be removed until it is no longer related to any CardSet.

From the [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001857-SW1)

> Deny
>
> If there is at least one object at the
>   relationship destination, then the
>   source object cannot be deleted.
>
> For
>   example, if you want to remove a
>   department, you must ensure that all
>   the employees in that department are
>   first transferred elsewhere (or
>   fired!) otherwise the department
>   cannot be deleted.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't do the trick, it simply makes it impossible to delete items.